# Null aware in dart list element

Tags: dart

I was working on a project and wanted to check if a list element was null. Example

```
List<int> i = [1, 2, 3];
print(i[1]); // this prints 2
```

But what if I want to print out a list element and if it does not exist print out a default number using dart null-aware. Example

```
List<int> i = [1, 2, 3];
print(i[10] ?? 15);
// Also tried
print(i?.elementAt(10) ?? 15);
```

I want it to print out 15 since the element at index 10 does not exist. Unfortunately, the above code gives me an error.

How can I check if a list element does not exist and return a default value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no elegant way of doing it, as you are trying to. **You will have to check the list length first**, because in the moment that the program evaluates `i.elementAt(10)` it inmediately throws the RangeError exception.

Example solution 1:

```
if (i.length > 9) { 
    print(i?.elementAt(10));
} else {
    print(15);
}
```

Example solution  2 (a more elegant way):

```
print(i.length > 9 ? i?.elementAt(10) : 15);
```

Comment: not an answer. just another everyday long route

Answer (score 4):

One solution to have this kind of functionality is to wrap your list with a custom class that catches the inner exception and returns null instead.

I wrote this wrapper bellow and called it XList:

```
class XList<E> {
  List<E> list;
  XList(this.list);
  E operator [](int position) {
    try {
      return list[position];
    } catch(IndexOutOfBoundException) {
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

Now your code works like this:

```
final list = [1, 2, 3];
final a = XList(list);
print(a[10] ?? 15);
// prints 15
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an extension on `Iterable` to easily have a method that returns `null` if the provided index is out of bounds:

```
extension SafeAccess<T> on Iterable<T> {
  T? safeElementAt(int index) => this.length <= index ? null : this.elementAt(index);
}
```

you can put this in a general-purpose file like `lib/extensions/iterable_extensions.dart` in your codebase and then import it whenever you need it.